# How to configure kafka s3 sink connector for json using its fields AND time based partitioning?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a json coming in like this:

```
{
    "app" : "hw",
    "content" : "hello world",
    "time" : "2018-05-06 12:53:04"
}
```

I wish to push to S3 in the following file format:

/upper-directory/$jsonfield1/$jsonfield2/$date/$HH

I know I can achieve:

/upper-directory/$date/$HH

with TimeBasedPartitioner and Topic.dir, but how do I put in the 2 json fields as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own Partitioner to achieve a combination of TimeBased and Field Partitioners

That means make a new Java project, [look at the source code for a reference point](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/FieldPartitioner.java), build a JAR out of the project, and then copy the jar into `kafka-connect-storage-common` on all servers running Kafka Connect, which is picked up by the S3 connector. After you've copy the JAR, you will need to reboot the Connect process.

Note: there's already a PR that is trying to add this - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/pull/73/files